# Linux Grub doesn't show up

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, bios

Last day I bought a laptop with NVIDIA G105M and Intel Core Duo Inside which has Windows 7 default. As a Linux fan, I wanted to install Ubuntu to my laptop and I plugged in my old live USB (which I used to install Ubuntu to my desktop computer) and followed instructions that the live USB said. But when I rebooted my computer, I got only a text cursor (top-left corner):

[image]

So I tried to install Ubuntu several times but I got nothing. So I searched on the web and saw that Nvidia users should use the `nomodeset` option. So I did it but it didn't solve my problem. I tried other Ubuntu versions but nothing changed. So I searched the web again and  found an article that says to me I should hold down the Shift key. I did and I got that screen:

[image: http://k1307.hizliresim.com/1c/p/qlr6n.bmp]

I tried another Linux distribution called Linux Mint but it gave me the same error. I reinstalled `grub2` 2 or 3 times again but it didn't work.  I tried boot-repairing but it didn't work either. I am lost. Am I doing something wrong? Should I update my BIOS or do what? Please help. I want my Ubuntu! :D

Edit:When I press the Shift Key I got thtis screen and When I use the "Ctrl+Alt+Delete Key Combination" my computer reboots so BIOS boots my kernel, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be these links are help full to your :-

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/reinstall-ubuntu-grub-bootloader-after-windows-wipes-it-out/

http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

and try to install dual boot ubuntu because you have preinstall windows 7.

it may be possible GRUB is not properly install in your pc or is booting from directly USB.

Dowload Easybcd software it is free for home user install it open it you will see add new entry click on it go to linux tab add entry click on select "GRUB2" edit boot menu select the appropriate timeout option and save setting

Download here: http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml

Comment: I reset my harddisk so don't have windows anymore and in installation of ubuntu There is no choise like "Install Alongside Windows" sometimes after I reset my HDD I got the "Erase Disk and Install ubuntu" and sometimes I got" Install Ubuntu Alongside Ubuntu" option so there is no windows anymore on my PC